# Event or callback when a WebHost has been started

Tags: c#, .net-core, kestrel

I have a .NET Core 2.0 web project. I need to perform an action after the WebHost has been started, and it is already listening for requests. I've already tried using `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted`, but it's not what I need.

Comment: Why does it not meet your need?

Comment: await `IWebHost.StartAsync` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder I need to run my action when the WebHost is already listening for requests. If I run in the ApplicationStarted event, requests are not yet being accepted.

Comment: @Selvin I'm not sure I get the difference between `Run` and `Start` (or their async versions); the documentation is very quick on that. Could you tell me a bit more?

Comment: You can use a IHostedService, and register it in `Program.cs` so the hosted service starts after the app is configured and ready to take requests. See this section of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface

Comment: You can also check this other blog post that explains it even better: https://andrewlock.net/controlling-ihostedservice-execution-order-in-aspnetcore-3/